# Function of inverse of a function and it's range

Tags: real-analysis, algebra-precalculus

Say we have:
$$f: X\rightarrow Y \space\space\space\space \forall\space\space A\subseteq Y$$
Then why
$$f(f^{-1}(A))\subseteq A$$
Can someone give a counterexample when this holds true?What function is it
$$f(f^{-1}(A))\subset A$$

Comment: Take any non-surjective map $f:X\to Y$. Then $f(f^{-1}(Y))=f(X)\neq Y$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take $B\subseteq X$ to be any arbitrary set. Let $f = \mathbb{1}_B$ to be the indicator function, i.e. $f(x) = 1$ iff $x\in B$. Take $A = [0.5,1.5]$. Then 
\begin{align}
f^{-1}(A) = B,\nonumber\\
f(f^{-1}(A)) \subset A
\end{align}

Comment: Indeed I didn't think that $A$ could not belong to it's inverse function domain. That's what we are trying to prove after all.